# Is geonames.org legit?

Tags: python, zip-codes, geonames

I recently was looking for the long/lat data on several different U.S. zip codes (several thousand) and came across this website made a while ago called: "geonames.org". I went to the website and found the respective files for the U.S. and downloaded them.

I noticed shortly after that the website sometimes shows as "secure" (https) in the search bar and other times it is "Not Secure" (HTTP) with the exclamation point next to the website URL. I'm a little worried I either clicked on the wrong website or a replica website that might have viruses. Can anyone else confirm that geonames.org is legit?

specific link used: http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

- Shows as "Not Secure" for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3):

It just means some of the links on the site have not been changed to use https yet. Since no one is paying to use the site I would guess it is maintained on a volunteer basis.

As for the risk of getting a virus, I wouldn't worry as you are downloading text files that are easy to inspect (even if you could embed a virus in a text file). However, as I'm a linux user I may not be paranoid enough about viruses.

Comment: Thanks! Just got a bit paranoid since I'm running Windows haha